# Unauthorize transaction unknown user

Tags: metamask, etherscan

Basically I sent my ETH from Metamask to my Ronin wallet last night because we just wanted to buy Axie to play Axie Infinity. We waited an hour or more to received. We visited the game because we already have the plan which to buy. Suddenly I just found out that after the ETH was sent from metamask to my ronin address there's another transaction ongoing without our authorization. We checked it in our activities in ronin but theres no transaction there and we really don't know who did that so we check it in EtherScan to see what's going on with our ETH, until we saw that our ETH ronin wallet just forwarded 2 unknown accounts separately. We dig deeper to see where our ETH will go. Found out that 1 account to another then from another account to the final. And yes we just found the main wallet address. Please help us solve this. Ill be uploading images below to see the transaction:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I'm not wrong Axie it a layer 2 app, and Ronin is the wallet to 'jump' the bridge. Did you try contacting Axie/Ronin developers? Did you download the wallet from the oficial site?

Comment: Yes sir you are right. Ronin is also used to play the game. I didn't tried contacting Ronin developers sir because I don't know their contact details or support. Yes sir basically I downloaded the wallet from the chrome official site.

Answer (score 1):

All compromised accounts are checked by bots and as soon as funds gets deposited the transaction to steal funds transfers them out immediately to thief's address.

your metamask wallet has been hacked

Comment: Hi sir. Even though I already have a different secret phase sir? I humbly ask also what can I do to prevent this hack sir. Any malware guard?